# How can i apply conditional formatting on a column by column basis in R on my data using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a datframe like the following:

```
group | amount_food | amount_finance | amount_clothes 
A     | 30          |  40            | 50 
B     | 34          |  43            | 53 
C     | 50          |  86            | 90
```

I would like to colour the contents of the cells depending on the value (a gradient of sorts where e.g. red would indicate higher and blue would indicate lower values etc). Similar to conditional formatting in excel. Ideally would like this done on a column by column basis, s i know which group has the highest amount_food etc.

How can i achieve this in R?

```
df <- read.csv("shopspend.csv")
```

new to R so any pointers helpful.

Comment: Your desired output is a table, where the background color of a cell corresponds with its value?

Comment: yes that is what i want, but i would like to achieve it in R

Comment: This is possible with the flextable (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/bg.html), gt (https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/data_color.html), and ztable (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ztable/vignettes/heatmapTable.html) packages.